# Автоматическое изменение шрифта в форме

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Задача такая: в зависимости от изменения размера формы все ее элементы (включая даже шрифт) должны меняться пропорционально. Как это сделать?

Comment: А что должно произойти, если ширина увеличилась вдвое, а высота — втрое?

Comment: Ну есть же какой нибудь умный алгоритм? Но я предполагаю что по минимальному.

Comment: А откуда умному алгоритму знать, что вам надо? Хорошо, если по минимальному, что делать со свободным местом? Если вначале окно было квадратным, а потом у него стало отношение сторон 2:3, и контент растянулся вдвое, то есть остался квадратным — где ему помещаться в окне?

Comment: Для этого есть свойство AutoSizeMode. Вопрос как это на шрифт распространить

Comment: @VladD можно попробовать плясать от начальной площади окна программы. К примеру, было 800x600, а стало 1024x768 => увеличиваем шрифт в 1.5 раза.

Comment: @BulsonЭто конечно интересное решение, но в идеале хотелось бы это распространить на любой размер. Просто где то видел как приложение на WPF увеличивали в размере и автоматически увеличивался шрифт. Причем это было сделано стандартными средствами.

Comment: @Bulson: Та же проблема выходит.

Comment: @polsok: Ну можно пойти через ViewBox, но вопрос, что делать со сменой AspectRatio, остаётся.

Comment: @polsok: Вы уж определитесь что используете: WinForms или WPF.

Comment: @D .Stark я буду использовать то где смогу реализовать такую возможность.

Comment: @polsok тебе тогда надо куча ифов настругать, чтобы если что то тогда  будет то, ну итд....тогда может быть и получится что-то годное в юзинье)

Comment: Без DataContext привязки такое сложно будет реализовать, а вот сделать умный конвертер размеров и выдачи результата, такое можно реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, какой дизайн вы хотите. Например, можно подогнать размер при помощи `Viewbox`:

```
<Grid Background="LightGray">
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid Background="White">
           <!-- тут контент -->
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Это выдаст такую картинку:

[image: сомнительного характера]

Плюсы: не разъезжается лэйаут. Минусы: серые «уши» по бокам смотрятся ужасно.